# Will a single atom of an element with greater atomic mass than the $\rm H_2O$ molecule sink in a cup of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, fluid-statics, atoms, molecular-dynamics

Will a single atom of an element with greater atomic mass than the H2O molecule sink in a cup of water?

A single atom or molecule of a substance is placed in a cup of water. Because of its specific gravity, I suppose it should sink. However, I have never heard about a colloidal system with a single molecule or element.

Comment: Brownian motion will work against such settling.

Comment: Not a single atom, but say you dissolve a bunch of really large, non-polar particles like Xenon, then they might aggregate and sink due to the [hydrophobic effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophobic_effect#Cause).

Answer (score 2):

Like dissolving cesium bromide in water? Entropy (the larger number of accessible microstates) makes atoms in a crystal on the bottom go in solution.

Comment: Why are there more microstates with the heavy atom at the bottom?

Comment: @FellowTraveller There are more microstates (possible positions) for an atom in solution than the position in the crystal. So a CsBr crystal will sink and then dissolve.

Comment: I get why it’ll dissolve. But not why it will sink.

Comment: @FellowTraveller The CsBr crystal has much higher density than water. So crystals sink, but independent heavy atoms will be evenly distributed in the whole volume.